# Can you refer to somebody using "they"?

Tags: genderless-pronouns, singular-they

In "The Troubles" of U2, there is this :

> Somebody stepped inside your soul
>   Somebody stepped inside your soul
>   Little by little they robbed and stole
>   Till someone else was in control

What I don't understand is why are we using "they" here ? Is this referring to the person that "stepped inside the soul" or is it about other people ?
**If it is referring to somebody, what are the rules that enables us to use they while it's one specific person that stepped inside the soul, and not multiple people ?**

Comment: You might find your answer if you search for *singular they*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*They* here can mean "he", "she", or "anyone else". It is a general word for any of those. [OxfordDictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/they) defines *they* in this sense as "Used to refer to a person of unspecified sex", and they also give the definition "People in general".

Comment: Thank you ! In fact what made me wonder this was that I saw a french translation of this song where people translated "they" like it was plural, which made no sense to me.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: In terms of traditional grammar, "they" is plural, but so is "you". There are some people who still frown upon the use of "they" as singular, but they're generally the type of people who think arbitrary grammar rules are more important than respect for other people. Having a non-gendered pronoun is important to avoid the sexist "he" when talking about an unknown/unspecific person where there's a traditional assumption that only a man would be in that role, and also for known people where their gender is unknown.